# I am trying to change the size of the div element dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the height and width of the div element dynamically by the input values of textbox. Here is the following code that I have written:
html code:

```
<input type="textbox" id="width" name="width">
<input type="textbox" id="height" name="height">
<button type="button" id="btn">ChangeSize</button>
<div id="sketch" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
fucntion changeWidth()
{
    document.getElementById("sketch").style.width =       document.getElementById("width").value;
}
function changeHeight()
{
    document.getElementById("sketch").style.height = document.getElementById("height").value;
}
documnet.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    changeWidth();
    changeHeight();
},false);
```

But the above code is npt working. Can you please let me know what mistake I have done in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check ans and fiddle posted below

Comment: `document.getElementById` is correct but `documnet.getElementById` is not

Answer (score 2):

Some typos and trivial mistakes,

```
function changeWidth() {
    document.getElementById("sketch").style.width = document.getElementById("width").value + "px";
}

function changeHeight() {
    document.getElementById("sketch").style.height = document.getElementById("height").value + "px"; // append unit to value.
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    changeWidth();
    changeHeight();
}, false);
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RFNa6/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

For starters you misspelled the word 'function' as 'fucntion' on line 1.

You also misspelled 'document' as 'documnet'.

I'm not one to judge.  I am the worst speller on Earth.

Comment: Also document is misspelled

Comment: Yeah, here i misspelled it but in my code it is correct.Though it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The values for width and height need to be a string with "px":

```
function changeWidth()
{
    document.getElementById("sketch").style.width = document.getElementById("width").value + "px";
}
function changeHeight()
{
    document.getElementById("sketch").style.height = document.getElementById("height").value + "px";
}
```